# Sum column totals depending on text of another column using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that I use to calculate totals in specific columns based on the text in a different column. It works just fine, but I'm learning, so I would like to know if there is way to consolidate this code. As you can see I run a "each()" twice, once for each column. The first each check for "A" in the first column, then goes to the second column and adds the rows that meet the criteria. Similar on the second column, just that it looks for "B" and add columns 3. Is there a way to run the each function only once and check both column at the same time?

JS:

```
//Second Column
var total = 0;
$("#theTable tr:contains('A') td:nth-of-type(2)").each(function () {
    var pending = parseInt($(this).text());
    total += pending;
});

$("#theTable tfoot tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(2)").text(total);

//Third Column
var total2 = 0;
$("#theTable tr:contains('B') td:nth-of-type(3)").each(function () {
    var pending2 = parseInt($(this).text());
    total2 += pending2;
});

$("#theTable tfoot tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(3)").text(total2);
```

HTML:

```
<table id="theTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>MONTH</th>
    <th>PENDING</th>
    <th>DENIED</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTALS:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

This may look simple for some of you, but again, I'm just learning some JS now.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML.

Comment: As a side note - it would be better to give some identification to your rows A and B - assign them a class. This would increase readability and improve selection speed (at least I think it should improve).

Comment: I can't do that, because I used A and B in this example to make things simple, but is reality it would be the months of the year, for several offices. Eventually I'll determine the current month, and add up the rows of each office that match current month. Again, the provided code works perfectly, I just would like to consolidate, because the real table that I'll be using is a lot bigger, and I would like to make the code more efficient. Makes sense?

Comment: Ideally you would have a separate data structure for storing the information. Parsing the HTML tree with complicated jQuery selectors is likely to slow things down. Even using the native `document.querySelector` function would improve your speed, though a separate data structure would help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var total = {A:{row:1,t:0},B:{row:2,t:0}};
$('#theTable tr').each(function() {
    $row = $(this);
    $.each(total, function(key, col) {
        rowFil = $row.filter(':contains("' + key + '")');
        col.t += (rowFil) ? +rowFil.find('td:eq(' + col.row + ')').text() : 0;
    });
});
$("#theTable tfoot tr:last td:eq(1)").text(total.A.t);
$("#theTable tfoot tr:last td:eq(2)").text(total.B.t);
```

Answer (score 1):

someThing of this sort might Help ...

```
var trs = $('#'+tblID).find('tr');

var total1 = 0;
var total2 = 0;
$.each(trs, function(k, v) {
    if ($(v).text == "A"){
    total1 += parseInt($(v).parent('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text());
    }
    if ($(v).text == "B"){
    total2 += parseInt($(v).parent('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text())
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your approach, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach - I've summed up all statistics for all possible values:

```
var totals = [];
$('#theTable tbody tr').each(function(e) {      
    var tds= $(this).find('td');
    var index = $(tds[0]).text();
    var pending = parseInt($(tds[1]).text(), 10);
    var denied = parseInt($(tds[2]).text(), 10);
    if (totals[index] == undefined)
        totals[index] = { Pending: 0, Denied: 0 };
    totals[index].Pending += pending;
    totals[index].Denied += denied;
});
for (var key in totals)
    $('#theTable tfoot').append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+
                            totals[key].Pending+'</td><td>'+totals[key].Denied+'</td></tr>');
```

I've also updated markup a little, here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgANW/). The code may be not so pretty, but doing more stuff and can be refactored.

Comment: This one works great too, and I like the statistics section. It is a shame I can not select two good answers. I chose the one above for its simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can combine both solutions to get something super special :)

Comment: Thanks, for your solution the only modification I had to make was to change the line `$('#theTable tbody tr').each(function (e)` to `$('#theTable tbody tr:not(:first)').each(function (e)`. I was getting a strange NaN row. Thanks again.

Comment: @cubanGuy, That's because in your original markup thead and tbody were messed up - see my jsfiddle, markup is correct there.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a second table with the sums makes it easier to analyse the data.

**[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/bikic/1/edit)**

JS

```
//make a list of unique months
var months = [];
$('#theTable tr td:nth-of-type(1)').each(function(){
  var month = $(this).text();
  if(months.indexOf(month) < 0) months.push(month);
});
console.log('months', months);

//make a data structure with sums
var data = {};
var tr = $('#theTable tr');
$.each(months, function(){
  var month = this;  
  data[month] = {
    pending: 0,
    denied: 0
  };
  tr.each(function(){
    var ch = $(this).children();
    var m = $(ch[0]).text();
    var pending = $(ch[1]).text();
    var denied = $(ch[2]).text();
    if(m == month) {
      data[month].pending += parseInt(pending);
      data[month].denied += parseInt(denied);
    }
  });
});
console.log('data', data);

//make a table with the data
var table = $('<table>');
table.append($('<tr>'+
  '<th>MONTH</th>'+
  '<th>PENDING</th>'+
  '<th>DENIED</th>'+
'</tr>'));
$.each(data, function(month){
  table.append($('<tr>'+
    '<td>'+month+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+data[month].pending+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+data[month].denied+'</td>'+
  '</tr>'));
});
$('body').append(table);
```